# Unable to convert object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am facing this error while i was trying to convert the session object type to int, I need to use that value in another query which is of datatype int.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=sport");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "select user_id from users where user_name='" + Session["usern"] + "'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Session["userid"] = reader;

        var uid = Convert.ToInt16(Session["userid"]);

        // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Please help me with this error !!

Comment: `Session["userid"] = reader` is the problem this is not the how a reader works at all... why do you think it is?;

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code is terrible -- it is totally going to get hacked by an injection attack.  You should be using a parameterized query.

as to your question, something like this would work but you really should be doing lots of error checking and sanity checks:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

Session["userid"] = reader[0];
```

You probably should have looked at the documentation which has some nice examples
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx